# Whats on my rosemary stem?

Tags: pest-control, container-gardening

[image]
I just noticed these little brown things on my rosemary...it does not seem to be harming anything else, no leaves were eaten, or brown. They dont move at all, no appendages, and seem quite attached to the stem. Does anyone know what they may be? The plant was outside for the summer, and now is on a window sill.

Comment: Well I've never seen anything quite like that - I'm assuming it's some sort of armoured scale insect.  Have you seen anything else, like white fluffy bits, anywhere else on the plant? If you have any rubbing alcohol or methylated spirits, try applying it on a cotton bud to the discs and see if you can get them off that way, to see what's underneath

Comment: Neither have I, are you sure they don't move? Have you tried pulling one of them off of the plant?

Comment: A bizarre and for some reason, vaguely disturbing (at least to me) life form. I thought "scale" when I first saw the post, but I didn't think scales had that much armor.

Comment: I pulled one off, and it seemed almost glued onto the stem, so a bit of bark came off with it. no white fuzzys or slime on the rest of the plant. It looks simular to  a seed, with the bottom the same as the top, broken open, it just has a bit of slime inside. Could it be an insect egg?

Answer (score 1):

I think Jurp is correct, some kind of scale.I have scale that look very similar except they are no more than 4 mm long. I remove them with my thumb nail and there it a little fluid or goo inside. Your Rosemary looks weak which would be caused by the scale. It attacks my stag-horn fern, sweet bay and sassafras seedlings.